# How do I apply na.locf on multiple colums in different data.frames, all ending with "price"

Tags: r

I've got list containing several data frames, each data frame of 2 comumns "date" and "XXX_price" - e.g. Boeing_price, GM_price ...

They are not in one sheet. Each company has a sheet on its own.

Now I would like to apply na.locf on all companies "price" column. Something like:

```
Q <- list(Boeing, GM; ...) 

Select from every company the column ending with "_price" and apply n.locf.
Afterwards I would like to add another column diff(log(XXX_price)).
Finally I would like to add all return columns in on sheet.
```

So to sum it up. I wopuld like to know how to apply functions on lists, how to name new columns and how to extract them. It must be someting with gsub.

But I've got no idea how to do.

```
Date   Boeing_price
12.11.2010  53.478
15.11.2010  53.918
16.11.2010  53.215
17.11.2010  52.978
18.11.2010  54.766
19.11.2010  53.901
22.11.2010  54.274
23.11.2010  53.91
24.11.2010  55.444
26.11.2010  54.927
29.11.2010  54.554
30.11.2010  54.054


Date    GM_Price
12.11.2010  #NA
15.11.2010  #NA
16.11.2010  #NA
17.11.2010  28.5455
18.11.2010  29.5749
19.11.2010  29.6355
22.11.2010  #NA
23.11.2010  28.7618
24.11.2010  28.9607
26.11.2010  29.2376
29.11.2010  #NA
30.11.2010  29.5836
```

Does anybody know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Using the data in the Note at the end try this:

```
library(zoo)

f <- function(data) {
  data[[2]] <- na.locf0(data[[2]])
  data
}

L2 <- lapply(L, f)
```

Another possibility is to merge the data frames into a single data frame and  convert that to a zoo or xts object and use that:

```
library(zoo)
z <- na.locf(read.zoo(do.call("merge", L)), na.rm = FALSE)
```

To get an xts object:

```
library(xts)
X <- as.xts(z)
```

### Note

We assume that the input data is as shown here in reproducible form:

```
Lines1 <- "Date   Boeing_price
12.11.2010  53.478
15.11.2010  53.918
16.11.2010  53.215
17.11.2010  52.978
18.11.2010  54.766
19.11.2010  53.901
22.11.2010  54.274
23.11.2010  53.91
24.11.2010  55.444
26.11.2010  54.927
29.11.2010  54.554
30.11.2010  54.054"
DF1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, na.strings = "#NA")
DF1$Date <- as.Date(DF1$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")

Lines2 <- "Date    GM_Price
12.11.2010  #NA
15.11.2010  #NA
16.11.2010  #NA
17.11.2010  28.5455
18.11.2010  29.5749
19.11.2010  29.6355
22.11.2010  #NA
23.11.2010  28.7618
24.11.2010  28.9607
26.11.2010  29.2376
29.11.2010  #NA
30.11.2010  29.5836"
DF2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, na.strings = "#NA",
 comment.char = "")
DF2$Date <- as.Date(DF2$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")

L <- list(DF1, DF2)
```